# How do search engine bots work?

Tags: search, indexing, web-crawler, bots

How are bots (that index for search engines) programmed and how do they operate?

Comment: The irony here is that a search engine could have answered this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10  Go to web page and get the html.
20  Index all the content in the page
30  Find all the links in that page
40  For each link in the page goto 10